# table NISHAN.TBL_ADMIN is mutating, trigger/function may not see it

Tags: oracle, triggers

I have a trigger named `tr_admin_user_role` that automatically insert values into `tbl_user_role` table when we perform a insert in another table called `tbl_admin`. There is no error at compile time but whenever I insert a value into `tbl_admin` table it shows me an error and error is like

[image]

This is my tbl_admin table

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_admin(
    admin_id INTEGER,
    username VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    passwords VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR2(100) UNIQUE,
    enabled CHAR(1) DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL,
    created_at DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_admin_id PRIMARY KEY(admin_id)
);
```

**tbl_user_role** table

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_user_role(
    user_role_id INTEGER,
    username VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
    user_role VARCHAR2(50) DEFAULT 'ROLE_ADMIN' NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_user_role_id PRIMARY KEY(user_role_id)
);
```

Trigger that i have created

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tr_admin_user_role
AFTER INSERT ON tbl_admin
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
new_username TBL_ADMIN.username%TYPE;
BEGIN

    SELECT username INTO new_username FROM (
        SELECT username FROM tbl_admin ORDER BY username DESC
    ) WHERE ROWNUM = 1;

    INSERT INTO tbl_user_role(username, user_role) VALUES(new_username, 'ROLE_ADMIN');
END;
```

Insert statement

```
INSERT INTO tbl_admin(username, passwords) VALUES('nisha', 'nisha');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how you fetch the newly inserted / updated / previous value of a column in a Trigger. You should use the `:OLD.column_name` and  `:NEW.column_name` to refer the old and new column values.Read the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/triggers.htm#LNPLS020) to understand more.

So, your Trigger could be rewritten as

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tr_admin_user_role AFTER
    INSERT ON tbl_admin
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tbl_user_role (
        username,
        user_role
    ) VALUES (
        :NEW.username,
        'ROLE_ADMIN'
    );

END;
/
```

I assume you are using another trigger to generate 
`admin_id` and `user_role_id` since they are declared as `PRIMARY KEY`s
and you are not including them in your inserts.

[**Db fiddle demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f0b2fcdee8412dfcc9195e0219d0ed06)

Here I've used dummy values for those columns.